# Highstock chart doesn't show correct width in Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, highcharts

I'm testing a Phonegap (2.2.0) application using Jquery Mobile (1.2.0) and Highstock charts. I have a javascript with jquery `ready` function which call my `graph()` function. Below that I put a div like this:

```
<div data-role="content" style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="container" style="height:220px; right:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Also, The highstock code is in a function.js file:

```
function graph(){

    $(function() {

      $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
                // Create the chart
                window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                     chart : {
                     renderTo : 'container' 
                     },
                     rangeSelector : {
                     selected : 1
                     },

                     title : {
                     text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
                     },

                     series : [{
                               name : 'AAPL',
                               data : data,
                               tooltip: {
                               valueDecimals: 2
                               }
                               }]
                     });
                });

      });
}
```

When I run it in Xcode, it doesn't adjust to the correct width.When i put the width and height manually i don't have any problem, but since i'm developing through cross platforms i would like to put it in % or like it just fill the right screen.
I tried with the min-width and height with no results, the charts is render in the index.html and if i render the chart with the function beforecreate i have better results but with performance issues.

Hope you can help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should use jQuery to calculate div dimensions. Lets say your graph page has an id  index:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    screenWidth = $('[data-role="page"]').first().width() - 30;  // -30 to counter content padding
    $('#container').css({'width': screenWidth,'height':screenWidth/2});
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') === 'index'){
        screenWidth = $('[data-role="page"]').first().width() - 30;  // -30 to counter content padding
        $('#container').css({'width': screenWidth,'height':screenWidth/2});    
    }
});
```

This div will be responsive to page resizing. I have also created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/bXsCV/